# Can I delete a named semaphore created with sem_open?

Tags: macos, semaphore

I am experimenting with the named semaphores and there is something that I don't understand about the behavior of `sem_close` and `sem_destroy`. In my example, it looks like the semaphore that I create does not get deleted.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <semaphore.h>

int main() {
  char sem_name[] = "/sem-1";

  {
    sem_t *sptr = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
    if (sptr != SEM_FAILED) {
      printf("sem_open success\n");

      // neither of these works
      sem_close(sptr);
      // sem_destroy(sptr);
    } else {
      printf("sem_open error #1: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
  }

  sem_t *sptr = sem_open(sem_name, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644, 0);
  printf("sem_open error #2: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  assert(sptr != SEM_FAILED);

  return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
sem_open success
sem_open error #2: File exists
Assertion failed: (sptr != SEM_FAILED), function main, file /tmp/delete_me/main.cpp, line 22.
```

I would expect the assertion to not be hit and also the error #2 to not shown.

Additionally, macOS says that the `sem_destroy` method is deprecated but I am still using both `sem_close()` and `sem_destroy` but they both seem to not delete the semaphore.

Background: I am trying to port NASA Core Flight System to macOS. Their POSIX implementation uses `sem_` calls and I am trying to understand if I can make them work on macOS with some minor modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `macOS` only recognizes **[`named`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_open.2.html)** semaphores, using `sem_destroy()` won't work. `sem_destroy()` destroys an unnamed semaphore at the address pointed to by sem. Only a semaphore that has been initialized by `sem_init()` should be
destroyed using `sem_destroy()`.

You could likely overcome this issue by using `sem_unlink`:

```
...
sem_close(sptr);
sem_unlink(sem_name);
...
```

> **SEM_UNLINK(2)**
>
> **NAME**
>        sem_unlink -- remove a named semaphore
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>  #include <semaphore.h>
>  int sem_unlink(const char *name);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>        The named semaphore named name is removed.  If the semaphore is in use by
>        other processes, then name is immediately disassociated with the sema-phore, semaphore,
>        phore, but the semaphore itself will not be removed until all references
>        to it have been closed.  Subsequent calls to `sem_open()` using name will
>        refer to or create a new semaphore named name.
>
> ```
>  If successful, `sem_unlink()` will return 0.  Otherwise, -1 is returned and
>  errno is set, and the state of the semaphore is unchanged.
> ```
>
> **ERRORS**
>        `sem_unlink()` succeeds unless:
>
> ```
>  [EACCES]           Permission is denied to be remove the semaphore.
>
>  [ENAMETOOLONG]     name exceeded SEM_NAME_LEN characters.
>
>  [ENOENT]           The named semaphore does not exist.
> ```

↳ [macOS Manual Pages | sem_unlink()](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sem_unlink.2.html)